# Signing and verification of messages using Ethereum key pair

Tags: dapps, signature

What are some libs to sign and verify messages using an Ethereum key pair?
I tried Ethersjs but it seems that it only supports signing (not verify). I need to use the lib on a React Native dapp. The verification will be offchain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `web3.js` (1.2.x or 1.3.x).

**[Sign a message](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-accounts.html#sign) :**

```
web3.eth.accounts.sign(data, privateKey);
```

The data is prefixed to make it impossible to sign a transaction :

> The value passed as the data parameter will be UTF-8 HEX decoded and wrapped as follows: "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + message.length + message.

Example from the doc :

```
web3.eth.accounts.sign('Some data', '0x4c0883a69102937d6231471b5dbb6204fe5129617082792ae468d01a3f362318');
> { //returns the signature object with the relevant information
    message: 'Some data',
    messageHash: '0x1da44b586eb0729ff70a73c326926f6ed5a25f5b056e7f47fbc6e58d86871655',
    v: '0x1c',
    r: '0xb91467e570a6466aa9e9876cbcd013baba02900b8979d43fe208a4a4f339f5fd',
    s: '0x6007e74cd82e037b800186422fc2da167c747ef045e5d18a5f5d4300f8e1a029',
    signature: '0xb91467e570a6466aa9e9876cbcd013baba02900b8979d43fe208a4a4f339f5fd6007e74cd82e037b800186422fc2da167c747ef045e5d18a5f5d4300f8e1a0291c'
}
```

**[Verify a message](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-accounts.html#recover) :**

```
web3.eth.accounts.recover(signatureObject);
```

With `signatureObject` including :

```
messageHash - String: The hash of the given message already prefixed with "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + message.length + message.
r - String: First 32 bytes of the signature
s - String: Next 32 bytes of the signature
v - String: Recovery value + 27
```

Example from the doc :

```
web3.eth.accounts.recover({
    messageHash: '0x1da44b586eb0729ff70a73c326926f6ed5a25f5b056e7f47fbc6e58d86871655',
    v: '0x1c',
    r: '0xb91467e570a6466aa9e9876cbcd013baba02900b8979d43fe208a4a4f339f5fd',
    s: '0x6007e74cd82e037b800186422fc2da167c747ef045e5d18a5f5d4300f8e1a029'
})
> "0x2c7536E3605D9C16a7a3D7b1898e529396a65c23" //returns the signer address
```

The `recover` function can also be used this way (see the [doc](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-accounts.html#recover) for more info):

```
web3.eth.accounts.recover(message, signature [, preFixed]);
web3.eth.accounts.recover(message, v, r, s [, preFixed]);
```